# Understanding this abstract Lagrangian of effective field theory

Tags: quantum-field-theory, lagrangian-formalism, renormalization, effective-field-theory, locality

I'm learning Wilson's approach to renormalization and the Effective Field Theory.  Typically, the theory is defined by a Lagrangian valid up to some scale $Λ$. I saw these two definitions for 4-dimensional spacetime:
$$
\mathcal{L} = \mathcal{L}_{\text{renormalizable}}+\sum_nc_n\frac{\mathcal O^{[d]}}{\Lambda^{d-4}}
$$
(this is the one from my lecture)
where $d$ is the dimension of the operator. Also,
$$
\mathcal{L} = \mathcal{L}^{d\leq4}+\sum_nc_n\frac{\mathcal O_n}{\Lambda^{n}}
$$
(from eqn. (1) of [this paper](https://doi.org/10.1140/epja/s10050-020-00089-w) ([PDF](https://core.ac.uk/reader/228085970))).
Both definitions divide the total theory into a finite sum and an infinite sum of local operators. I'm wondering if these two definitions are the same, and what is the meaning of 'local' here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The two definitions are the same since in $d=4$ the (power-counting) renormalizable operators are those with dimension $d \leq 4$.

"Local" operator means the operator can be written as a finite sum of positive powers of derivatives. For example, $\phi^n$ and $\phi^n(\partial \phi)^m$ are local, but $\frac{1}{\text{const.} + (\partial \phi)^2}$ or $\frac{1}{(\partial \phi)^2}$ are not. The terminology comes from the fact that these nonlocal operators can be written as something like $\phi(x) G(x,y) \phi(y)$ for some function $G(x,y)$, for example (think about how one often inverts the Klein–Gordon operator and gets a Green function). Notice then how the interaction depends not on one, but on two spacetime events. Therefore, it is nonlocal.

Comment: This definition of local operator is the one used in Percacci's [*An Introduction to Covariant Quantum Gravity and Asymptotic Safety*](https://doi.org/10.1142/10369), p. 135.

Comment: Thanks so much for the answer, why the power on $\Lambda$ is $d-4$?

Comment: @IGY $d$ seems to be the dimension of the operator (and it is related to $n$ somehow). $d-4$ is the correct factor to make sure the action has the correct dimensions. The $4$ comes from the spacetime volume in the integral that defines the action